# Smooth element motion on canvas with KeyDown event UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to create kind of a spaceship game, where you control an image (of a spaceship obviously) with the arrow keys, to move UP/DOWN/R/L.
For this I use a CoreWindow.KeyDown event.

It actually works fine, but the motion is not smooth enough.
Every time I press one of the arrow keys, the image then:
1. Moves one step to that direction
2. FREEZES, for like half a second (even less)
3. Then continue on moving with no trouble.
(A "step", is an 'int' variable the holds a number of pixels, say, 20).

Of course, that is no way to run a game. I want the ship to move smoothly immediately when i press one of the arrow keys with no "Half a second" delay.
This is my code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    double playerYAxisPosition;
    double playerXAxisPosition;
    int steps = 20;
    bool upMovement;
    bool downMovement;
    bool rightMovement;
    bool leftMovement;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_KeyUp;
    }

    // Recognizes the KeyDown press and sets the relevant booleans to "true"
    private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args) {
        playerYPosition = (double) playerShip.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
        playerXPosition = (double) playerShip.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);

        if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up) {
            upMovement = true;
        }
        else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down) {
            downMovement = true;
        }
        else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left) {
            leftMovement = true;
        }
        else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right) {
            rightMovement = true;
        }
        movePlayer();
    }

    // recognizes the KeyUp event and sets the relevant booleans to "false"
    private void CoreWindow_KeyUp(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args) {
        if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up) {
            upMovement = false;
        }
        else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down) {
            downMovement = false;
        }
        else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left) {
            leftMovement = false;
        }
        else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right) {
            rightMovement = false;
        }
    }

    // Calls the movement Methods of the relevant direction
    private void movePlayer() {
        if (upMovement) {
            moveUp();
        }
        if (downMovement) {
            moveDown();
        }
        if (rightMovement) {
            moveRight();
        }
        if (leftMovement) {
            moveLeft();
        }
    }

    private void moveUp() {
        playerShip.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, playerYPosition - stepsToMove);
    }

    private void moveDown() {
        playerShip.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, playerYPosition + stepsToMove);
    }

    private void moveRight() {
        playerShip.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, playerXPosition + stepsToMove);
    }

    private void moveLeft() {
        playerShip.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, playerXPosition - stepsToMove);
    }
```

By the way, the reason I created some dedicated booleans that will be set to 'true' or 'false' on every KeyDown event, and not used the KeyDown event directly, is because that separation allows the element (the ship image) to move diagonally as well, while using the "args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.SomeArrowKey" directly does not allow it from some reason.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want create a game, you should move `playerShip` in your game loop. You can use [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) or register [CompositionTarget.Rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br228127) event to create a game loop.

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
```

Change `CoreWindow_KeyDown` event handler as follows:

```
private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)
    {
        upMovement = true;
    }
    else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down)
    {
        downMovement = true;
    }
    else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left)
    {
        leftMovement = true;
    }
    else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right)
    {
        rightMovement = true;
    }
}
```

Next, move your ship in `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event handler.

```
private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, object e)
{
    playerYPosition = (double)playerShip.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
    playerXPosition = (double)playerShip.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
    movePlayer();
}
```

Comment: I turned google upside down for this..
Thank you very much!
Problem solved :)